# I'm trying to set up a Template for large Projects in Azure DevOps, but hit the limits. Is there another tool that I can use to do this?

Tags: azure, templates, devops

We use the same Project template for all our projects but can't seem to find a way to use a template in Azure DevOps.

I have tried using the Extractor tool but I have about 500 work items (with the complication of parent child relationship as well) so this doesn't work since there is a limit of 200 items.  Anyone else have a tool or used something else to get this done?

Comment: What kind of Project template do you mean? How it is related to work items and Extractor?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Azure DevOps Demo Generator to create the template. For the 500 work items export them to Excel using the Excel Extension.

To do ensure that you keep the relationships between the work items, create a query using a tree of work items. Filter the tree with the child and parent option.